# How to get the file/line/function that made __penter be called?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function, instrumentation

In my program, I am currently instrumenting `__penter` and `__pexit` in order to do some low-level diagnostics of the application. However, I am currently stuck at how to retrieve the basic information related to which function actually made `__penter` or `__pexit` to be called in the first place.

In particular, I am interested in getting the name of file, the number of line and the name of function (the function name being the most important). Of course, my first attempt was just using `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and `__FUNCTION__`, but obviously this does not work because they only actually retrieve the information of the `__penter` or `__pexit` functions themselves.

For instance, `__FUNCTION__` merely returns `__penter` or `__pexit`.

How could I retrieve the correct information I mentioned above? I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I am interested in doing this both for x86 and x64.

Comment: You would normally use the `_ReturnAddress` intrinsic to record the function address.  And, later, use the DebugHlp api to map it to a name.

Comment: Can you in code detect your error state? Then insert a debugbrk() and attach the debugger and you can check the call stack.